# Doctor Heinrich's aiming device

Tags: the-bureau-xcom-declassified

When you encounter doctor Heinrich for the first time he mentions creating a device that helps you aim. And that you should test it out on the shooting range. Naturally, I got nothing and going to the shooting range did nothing new. Did I miss something? Or was it just set dressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dialogue is misleading.  Either it refers to a quest in an earlier build, or it refers to the device that Carter and other agents wear on their wrists in all but the opening sequence.  Personally, I suspect it's the second one.  It's pretty much the only in-game mention of a rather conspicuous bit of tech, until the device gets used at a critical plot point.

Either way, the wording implies there's a quest and a new device.  There isn't, and there's no further dialogue (and nothing more to do).  There's no testing to do, and no "reporting back."

Source: Personal experience (all Steam achievements) and [this thread on Xbox Achievements.com](http://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/showthread.php?t=518365), where many other people moan over hours lost due to poor playtesting.